# Insert document as tab in master spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am a school secretary.  I created a master schedule in sheets.  Based on that schedule, I sent a separate sheet to each teacher to create their own personal schedule.  I created tabs and cut and paste each personal schedule into a specific tab/sheet labeled with that teacher's name.  I did not want to cut and paste.  I wanted to insert their actual document as a tab in the master file.  How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I'm doing something similar for a school. If a script is a reasonable response, I'll write you something up- page 1 would be the teachers by name/email, page two would be your template, then run it and it created documents shared with those teachers and add pages with live linking to the created sheets via import.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, but the most simple I think as it doesn't require an add-on nor a script is the following one:

1. Open each teacher spreadsheet
2. Check that the sheet has the teacher name
3. Click in the sheet name tab, select "Copy to..."
4. Select the master schedule or paste the URL

   1. You could write the master schedule spreadsheet name or go to the recent tab
5. Click Select